# DEFINE CHANNEL fails with AMQ8242E: SSLCIPH definition wrong

Tags: windows, ibm-mq

When using an *none administrative* account on Windows 10 I am getting this warning and error:

```
     1 : DEFINE CHANNEL('DEV.APP.SVRCONN') CHLTYPE(CLNTCONN) TRPTYPE(TCP) DEFRECON(YES) QMNAME('QM1') CONNAME('DEV.APP.CLIENTCONN') MAXMSGL(4194304) DESCR('Client Connection Channel') CERTLABL('ibmwebspheremqqm1') SSLCIPH(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256)  REPLACE
17/11/2021 09:43:26 Unable to access the configuration data.
Unable to access the configuration data.
AMQ8242E: SSLCIPH definition wrong.
One MQSC command read.
No commands have a syntax error.
One valid MQSC command could not be processed.
```

But this scripts runs fine when I run the script with administrative access.
The complicated thing is that I get two errors, one about not being able to access the configuration data (which is to be expected) but the other one is about a wrong cipherspec, which I did not expect since this command runs fine with administrative rights.

Any thoughts about this?

Comment: SSLCIPH(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256) is not deprecated, so the AMQ8242E should not apply to it. I wonder if the error path is being confused by the first error. If you get that fixed, the latter one may go away. You seem to thing the first one is expected. Do you know how to get it fixed?

Comment: It might indeed be a flaw in the MQ error handling routine. That even though the system knows that the cipher check is unnecessary, since it cannot access the config file,  it still fires the check and throws an error.